# Regex to replace string

Tags: c#, regex

I tried to replace `&nbsp;` elements in a string using .NET regex - with no luck :)

Assume the following string:

`&nbsp;AA&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;D&nbsp;&nbsp; A&nbsp;Some Text &nbsp; here`

The rules

1. Do not replace at beginning of line
2. Do only replace single occurrences
3. Do not replace if a space is before or after it (optional)

The desired result from above is (# as replacement character):

`&nbsp;AA#A&nbsp;&nbsp;C#D&nbsp;&nbsp; A#Some Text &nbsp; here`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover all 3 of your requirements. Excuse the formatting; I had to back-tick the first few lines for the `&nbsp;` to show up properly.

`string pattern = @"(?<!^|&nbsp;)((?<!\s)&nbsp;(?!\s))(?!\1)";`

`string[] inputs = { "&nbsp;AA&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;D&nbsp;&nbsp; A&nbsp;Some Text &nbsp; here", // original`

`"&nbsp;AA&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;D&nbsp;&nbsp; A &nbsp;Some Text &nbsp; here" // space before/after`

`};`

```
foreach (string input in inputs)
{
    string result = Regex.Replace(input, pattern, "#");
    Console.WriteLine("Original: {0}\nResult: {1}", input, result);
}
```

**Output:**

`Original: &nbsp;AA&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;D&nbsp;&nbsp; A&nbsp;Some Text &nbsp; here`

`Result: &nbsp;AA#A&nbsp;&nbsp;C#D&nbsp;&nbsp; A#Some Text &nbsp; here`

`Original: &nbsp;AA&nbsp;A&nbsp;&nbsp;C&nbsp;D&nbsp;&nbsp; A &nbsp;Some Text &nbsp; here`

`Result: &nbsp;AA#A&nbsp;&nbsp;C#D&nbsp;&nbsp; A &nbsp;Some Text &nbsp; here`

Comment: Thank's a lot. Next time I'll simple send you my sources to fix :)
Excellent example!!!

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with C#'s particular regex flavor but in PERL/PHP style this works for me:

`s/(?<!\A| |&nbsp;)&nbsp;(?!&nbsp;| )/#/g`

This relies on negative lookbehind, negative lookahead and the \A = start of input escape sequence.

Comment: Would (with some modifications) work - thanks.
I choose Ahmads answer since it solves the whole problem.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the following example :

`string s = Regex.Replace(original, "(?<!(&nbsp;| |^))&nbsp;(?!(&nbsp;| ))", "#");`

Comment: yea I had the same problem... use the back tick not the 4 space indention.

Comment: @beggs: Thanks, was just trying to figure that out. Will edit.

Comment: You could shorten it further to `(?<!&nbsp;| |^)&nbsp;(?!&nbsp;| )`

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.replace.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You may use this one

```
[^^\s(nbsp;)](nbsp;)[^$\s(nbsp;)]
```